# Template parameter accepting pointer to class member function

Tags: c++

```
#include <utility>

class Base {
public:
    virtual ~Base() {}
    virtual void base() {}
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    virtual void derived() {}
};

template<typename... Params>
using MemberFuncPtr = void(Derived::*)(Params...);

template<typename... Params, typename... Args>
void wrapper(MemberFuncPtr<Params...> ptr, Args&&... args)
{
    Derived* d = new Derived();

    (d->*ptr)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);

    delete d;
}

int main()
{
    wrapper(&Derived::derived);
    wrapper(&Derived::base);
    return 0;
}
```

Trying to run this code (GCC 7.0) gives me the following error:

```
prog.cc: In function 'int main()':
prog.cc:33:27: error: no matching function for call to 'wrapper(void (Base::*)())'
     wrapper(&Derived::base);
                           ^
prog.cc:18:6: note: candidate: template<class ... Params, class ... Args> void wrapper(MemberFuncPtr<Params ...>, Args&& ...)
 void wrapper(MemberFuncPtr<Params...> ptr, Args&&... args)
      ^~~~~~~
prog.cc:18:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
prog.cc:33:27: note:   mismatched types 'Derived' and 'Base'
     wrapper(&Derived::base);
                           ^
```

I don't really understand why method from the base class is an issue? It's also a method for derived class. I've done simple test where I assigned `Derived::base` to `Derived::*ptr` type and that worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I don't really understand why method from the base class is an issue?

It's just a matter of what the types are. The type of `&Derived::derived` is `void (Derived::*)()`, but the type of `&Derived::base` is `void (Base::*)()`. That doesn't match `void (Derived::*)(Args...)`, so deduction fails. Template deduction doesn't allow for conversions, even if a valid one exists in this case.

> I've done simple test where I assigned `Derived::base` to `Derived::*ptr` type and that worked.

This:

```
MemberFuncPtr<> d = &Derived::base;
wrapper(d);
```

works because now `d` is of the right type (it now *does* match `void (Derived::*)(Args...)`), and the first line is fine because it's valid to convert a pointer to member of a base class to a pointer to member of a derived class.

Comment: What I think I should remember is that template deduction doesn't allow conversions. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> I don't really understand why method from the base class is an issue?

@Barry has already explained the why in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41831457/4987285).
As a side note, note that you can further generalize it and get it working:

```
// ...

template<typename T, typename... Params>
using MemberFuncPtr = void(T::*)(Params...);

template<typename T, typename... Params, typename... Args>
void wrapper(MemberFuncPtr<T, Params...> ptr, Args&&... args)
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I was worried that I will be forced to cast in the call site to `void(Derived::*)()`. Good to know that additional parameter can handle this "different class type" issue.